# AS3 - Can Bitmap classes dispatch mouse events?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashdevelop

I'm trying to learn AS3 and have run into a small problem.

I have a Bitmap class to which I add a `MouseEvent.CLICK` listener, but the event doesn't seem to be dispatched.

I use Flashdevelop to write AS3 code and Flex to compile.

I have two classes, `Enemy.as` and `Player.as`

The `Player.as` looks like this:

```
package Player 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

[Embed(source="../../assets/leek.swf", symbol="Leek")]

public class Player extends Sprite 
{
    public function Player() 
    {
        trace("Player constructed");
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
    }

    private function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        trace("Clicked Player");
    }

}

}
```

The `Enemy.as` looks like this:

```
package enemies 
{

import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.MouseEvent

[Embed(source="../../assets/gardengnome.png")]

public class Enemy extends Bitmap 
{
    public function Enemy() 
    {
        trace("enemy constructed");
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
    }

    private function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        trace("Clicked Enemy");
    }

}

}
```

The two classes are pretty much identical except that one is a `Sprite` and I embedded a symbol from a `swf` file that I got from a tutorial, and the other is a `Bitmap` and I embedd a `png` file into that.

The `Player` class (the one that's a sprite and uses a symbol) fires off the `MouseEvent.CLICK` when I run the project and click on the Player image, but the `Enemy` class does not.

There are no compile warnings or errors, so I'm having a hard time understanding what is the issue exactly. Is it because one is a `Sprite` and the other a `Bitmap`, or is it because one uses a prepared symbol from a `swf`, while the other is just a `png`?

How can I make a `Bitmap` class respond to `MouseEvent`?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [ActionScript® 3.0 Reference for the Adobe® Flash® Platform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html):

> The Bitmap class is not a subclass of the InteractiveObject class, so
>   it cannot dispatch mouse events. However, you can use the
>   addEventListener() method of the display object container that
>   contains the Bitmap object.

Comment: Oh, that's so simple. I can just add the bitmap into a sprite container and voila. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `Bitmap` class doesn't dispatch mouse events you will have to wrap it inside a `Sprite` class.